# Use different layouts in HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So this is what im trying to do, but im really bad at html and css, the thing is that i have questions about how to accomplish what's shown in the picture, and also want to know how can i use differents layouts in a div or how can i organize those controls like in the image, im used to use layout in android so perhabs that's why i find it kinda confusing, any help is appreciated.

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9bYR.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <style>

        form{
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .botones{
            padding: 10px 10px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            /**margin-left: 30px;**/
        }

        #botonNuevo{
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

    </style>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('TablePersonal').DataTable();
        })

        $(TablaPersonal).DataTable

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

    <div>

        <form>
            <table id="TablaPersonal" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No. Expediente</th>
                    <th>No. Empleado</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>RFC</th>
                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                    <th>Puesto</th>
                    <th>Lugar de Asignación</th>
                    <th>Estatus</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="marker">1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class=" btn-group botones">
        <button id="botonNuevo" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Nuevo</button><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Inactivar</button><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled btn-block">Modificar</button><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled btn-block">Exportar</button><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled btn-block">Eliminar</button><br>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bootsrap Grid System as shown in [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp), wrap your table and button in a row `<div class="row">` and wrap your table with `<div class="col-sm-8>"` and wrap your button with `<div class="col-sm-4>"`, and adjust your button width. Just read more the bootstrap documentation about their grid system, ah I also remove your `#bottonNuevo` style, or you can also adjust it on your own. For the search button and the form, also just play with the bootstrap grid system

Comment: Thanks, i will use it, and see if i can copy that layout in the picture